# android set custom value to a custom textview programmatically

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have a Custom Class of `TextView` . I have implemented gradient attribute as the color of textview.
But i only managed to implement it in `xml`. I'm new to custom views. I don't know how can I add `setStartColor` , `setEndColor` in my custom TextView class.

**values/attr**

```
<declare-styleable name="GradientTextView">
    <attr name="startColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="endColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**GradientTextView**

```
public class GradientTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    public GradientTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a=context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.GradientTextView);
        int startColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.GradientTextView_startColor, Color.WHITE);
        int endColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.GradientTextView_endColor, Color.WHITE);
        Shader myShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100,startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        this.getPaint().setShader(myShader);
        a.recycle();
    }  
}
```

**XML**

```
<mehran.design.GradientTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:startColor="@color/yellow"
    app:endColor="@color/blue"/>
```

Comment: add the `setStartColor` and `setEndColor` methods, and do the same thing as you do in constructor

Comment: Wrap the shader logic inside a helper method and call this method internally inside `setStartColor(int)` and `setEndColor(int)` -- after updating the fields `startColor` and `endColor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define variable `startColor` and `endColor`
and also setters for it

like

```
public void setStartColor(int color) {
    this.startColor= color;
    --- do your logic----
    invalidate();
}
```

Reference [Link](https://github.com/e4basil/PercentageProgressBar)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public class GradientTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
        public GradientTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);

        }
        public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            TypedArray a=context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.GradientTextView);
            int startColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.GradientTextView_startColor, Color.WHITE);
            int endColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.GradientTextView_endColor, Color.WHITE);
            Shader myShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100,startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            this.getPaint().setShader(myShader);
            a.recycle();
        }  

        public void setCustomColor(int startColor,int endColor){
            Shader myShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100,startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            this.getPaint().setShader(myShader);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```